# Simple Injector decoratee factory in scoped proxy decorators

Tags: c#, simple-injector

Regarding the [docs of SimpleInjector](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aop.html#decorators-with-func-t-decoratee-factories) on using the decorator pattern with decoratee factories, I've run into the following problem.

Suppose I have a similar `ThreadScopedCommandHandlerProxy<T>` with the following implementation:

```
public class LifetimeScopeCommandHandlerProxy<T> : ICommandHandler<T>
{
    private readonly IScopeStarter _scopeStarter;
    private readonly IServiceFactory<ICommandHandler<T>> _decorateeFactory;

    public LifetimeScopeCommandHandlerProxy(
        IScopeStarter scopeStarter,
        IServiceFactory<ICommandHandler<T>> decorateeFactory)
    {
        _scopeStarter = scopeStarter;
        _decorateeFactory = decorateeFactory;
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public void Handle(T command)
    {
        using (_scopeStarter.BeginScope())
        {
            ICommandHandler<T> handler = _decorateeFactory.CreateInstance();
            handler.Handle(command);
        }
    }
}
```

Normally I would've injected a `Func<ICommandHandler<T>>` into the proxy, but I wanted to abstract away from this and created a IServiceFactory which internally just does this:

```
public class SimpleInjectorServiceFactory<TService> : IServiceFactory<TService>
{
    private readonly Func<TService> _factory;

    public SimpleInjectorServiceFactory(Func<TService> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public TService CreateInstance()
    {
        return _factory.Invoke();
    }
}
```

You can see the reasoning behind this by looking at the class name, this is a Simple Injector specific factory. Now I know that using a factory abstraction like this would introduce a code smell. But in this case it should only be used as an infrastructural component. The idea is that I want the Proxy to be something that can be consumed by multiple libraries/applications, so making it a generic component within the application's architecture.

Now the problem is of course, that I get the following exception:

```
For the container to be able to use LifetimeScopeCommandHandlerProxy<TCommand>
as a decorator, its constructor must include a single parameter
of type ICommandHandler<TCommand> (or Func<ICommandHandler<TCommand>>)
- i.e. the type of the instance that is being decorated.
The parameter type ICommandHandler<TCommand> does not currently exist
in the constructor of class LifetimeScopeCommandHandlerProxy<TCommand>.'
```

Now this exception message is crystal clear, and I understand the reasoning behind this. But still, I'd like to know if it's possible to bypass the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to know if it's possible to bypass the exception

There is no way to do this, without completely bypassing and reimplementing Simple Injector's decorator sub system.

Simple Injector's sub system intercepts the building of a service by wrapping a decorator. Although the decorator sub system will outsource the creation of the decorator and its dependencies back to Simple Injector's core infrastructure, it will override the creation of the dependency that capture the decorated instance. This behavior is hard-coded in the decorator sub system, which means it is impossible to move the type's decoratee to a sub class of the decorator.

Comment: Clear answer, but unfortunate. Would you advice against the abstraction I tried to introduce?

Comment: @QuantumHive: I would actually. To me it seems to provide no benefit, and when moving the `ICommandHandler<T>` abstraction out of the decorator, it becomes very unintuitive that the `IServiceFactory` is used to resolve the decoratee. `IServiceFactory` seems like your typical Service Locator, so someone might not expect that a resolve from it would return a 'peeled' version of the service (with one or multiple decorators stripped off).

Comment: I agree. What advice would you give if you wanted to make the proxy a reusable, external and generic component for one's architecture? Because the `Func<T> decorateeFactory` seems unintuitive in a similar way because the type does not reveal the actual intend (other than the argument's name, which was the same as the `IServiceFactory`). Also when one does not use *Simple Injector* as it's DI vendor, the reusable component might introduce usability issues. It might seem as an implicit vendor lock-in, right?

Comment: @QuantumHive: You can't really work around this type of vendor lock-in. You are locked-in to Simple Injector because of its unique and compelling features, not because you depend on framework-specific types. You should design the system the way it makes most sense to you and choose your libraries and frameworks accordingly. That seems to be what you did. Still, if you find another library that supports this, you can still swap. And without a DI Container (a.k.a. Pure DI) you can _always_ do this. Choose your tools wisely.

Comment: Although the name might not be that intuitive to some, this design can be considered a pattern or template. You might need to educate other developres about this. Still, a different way of designing a similar decorator is hard to imagine, and only depending on basic .NET types is actually the best thing you can get, since it prevents the dependency on tool-specific abstractions and types.